# Sequelize Validiation Enough for Duplicate Username?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

So i have this sequelize model of an Organization:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Organization = sequelize.define("organization", {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false
      },
      organizationName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        notEmpty: true,
        unique: {
          args: 'username',
          msg: 'This username is already taken!'
        }
      },
      emailAddress: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          isEmail: true
        },
        unique: {
          args: 'email',
          msg: 'The email is already taken!'
       }
      },
      physicalAddress: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true
      },
      city: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
          allowNull: false
      },
      country: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
          allowNull: false
      },
      phone: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          allowNull: true
      },
      websiteAddress: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
          allowNull: true
      }
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        underscored: true,
        freezeTableName: true
    });

    return Organization;
  };
```

When the user registers with a new Organization i want to make sure that the username entered is unique.

My question is... Is my implementation enough? Or should i be doing a `organization.find` before insert?

It does work but I'm worried.

I am aware that with the above method the id gets auto incremented even if validation fails. But are there any other issues?

Comment: Personally I think, it's not a good practice to make yourself dependend on a framework to handle and validate your application rules... it should work however...

Comment: You can do `findOrCreate()`  https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-finders.html#-code-findorcreate--code-

Comment: nice one @SujeetAgrahari :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are relying on the DB kicking out an error if the name is not unique. This should be a last resort really and would recommend you query your table before you attempt an insert. However, you could look at the upsert style operations like [findOrCreate](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-finders.html#-code-findorcreate--code-)

Additional Thought:
It would be less strain on your db, more scalable, and a better experience for your users, if you kept a cached list of existing usernames and searched that *before* you attempt the insert - as part of your validation process. Ideally, this would be called from an ajax query when the user has entered the organizational name.

UPDATE on some catching ideas:
[Redis](https://redis.io/) is a great start. It's widely adopted and implemented at all major providers like AWS, Heroku, Azure, etc. It's simple to provision and effortless to set up locally. Having a central, shared cache allows you to share data between your web/api instances, will be substantially faster to query, and takes the strain off your DB when cached data will suffice. I like the [ioredis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis) driver.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate on the cached list solution? How does one implement this ?

Comment: Added some notes on